# SQL Processor error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

When I try to run a query

```
SELECT 
    App.AppName, 
    DATEDIFF(second, DISPDATE, RTSDATE) AS IncidentLengthSeconds        
    --,[FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].*
FROM 
    FDMTEST.[dbo].[IncApp]
JOIN 
    FDMTEST.dbo.Inc ON IncApp.IncId = Inc.Id
JOIN 
    FDMTEST.dbo.App AS App ON IncApp.AppId = App.Id
WHERE 
    RTSDATE > REDEPDATE  
    AND AppName IN ('E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4') 
    AND inc.incdate >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00' 
    AND inc.incdate <= '2012-12-31 00:00:00'
```

I get the error

> Msg 535, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

The obvious answer is that some result for DATEDIFF(second, DISPDATE, RTSDATE) is to large but the largest gap in minutes is 331 minutes.

Now the really interesting part. If I uncomment ",[FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].*" the query no longer crashes. I figure some kind of internal optimization that MS-SQL server is doing is causing the issue.

All the tables mentioned are normal tables and not views.

> Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP1) - 11.0.3128.0 (X64)
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
>   Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

EDIT:
I found a record with incdate = 1993-10-29 12:55:00.000 and DISPDATE = '1800-01-01 00:00:00.000'

This record was filtered out with the WHERE clause but is it possible that SQL server was calculating the DATEDIFF anyways?

Plans:

```
  |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[IncId])=([FDMTEST].[dbo].[Inc].[Id]))
       |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([App].[Id])=([FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[AppId]))
       |    |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[App].[UQ_App] AS [App]), SEEK:([App].[AppName]='E1' OR [App].[AppName]='E2' OR [App].[AppName]='E3' OR [App].[AppName]='E4') ORDERED FORWARD)
       |    |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1008]=datediff(second,[FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[DISPDATE],[FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[RTSDATE])))
       |         |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[PK__IncApp__4ED38FEE]), WHERE:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[RTSDATE]>[FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[REDEPDATE]))
       |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[Inc].[INC_EventIndex1]), SEEK:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[Inc].[INCDATE] >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND [FDMTEST].[dbo].[Inc].[INCDATE] <= '2012-12-31 00:00:00.000') ORDERED FORWARD)
```

And with the comment uncommitted (working version):

```
  |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([App].[Id])=([FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[AppId]))
       |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[App].[UQ_App] AS [App]), SEEK:([App].[AppName]='E1' OR [App].[AppName]='E2' OR [App].[AppName]='E3' OR [App].[AppName]='E4') ORDERED FORWARD)
       |--Hash Match(Inner Join, HASH:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[Inc].[Id])=([FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[IncId]))
            |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[Inc].[INC_EventIndex1]), SEEK:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[Inc].[INCDATE] >= '2012-01-01 00:00:00.000' AND [FDMTEST].[dbo].[Inc].[INCDATE] <= '2012-12-31 00:00:00.000') ORDERED FORWARD)
            |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1008]=datediff(second,[FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[DISPDATE],[FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[RTSDATE])))
                 |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[PK__IncApp__4ED38FEE]), WHERE:([FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[RTSDATE]>[FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].[REDEPDATE]))
```

From what I can see it is calculating the scalar before the filter in one case but not in the other. Is there a way to force this execution early?

Comment: To confirm,  you've run `SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(minute, DISPDATE, RTSDATE)) FROM ...` on the same query and the result is 331?

Comment: I changed the first line to SELECT App.AppName, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DISPDATE, RTSDATE) AS IncidentLengthSeconds and sorted by IncidentLengthSeconds

Comment: Can you create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example that we can use to reproduce the issue?    http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If I remove the part "AND AppName IN ('E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4') " the query runs and the max is 40020 seconds

Comment: @TabAlleman sadly no, the issue only exists in the way that SQL server processes these exact tables. This is the minimal version I can build. if I remove anything else it work.

Comment: Hi! Could you attach plans of two queries: 1) comment is on 2) comment is off ? I'm talking about `,[FDMTEST].[dbo].[IncApp].*`

Comment: I dont know what is causing your issue, but after your edit may i suggest a workaround. Create a subquery `SELECT App.AppName, DISPDATE, RTSDATE ...` and then do a `DATEDIFF` query using that.

Comment: After comparing the two plans I did come up with a reason I just don't have a great way to control the plan.

Comment: Is using a table hint an option? How about applying SP2?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off writing the expression in your `SELECT` clause so that it will always produce a result without overflowing. As you've discovered, the optimizer may evaluate the expressions you `SELECT` even on records that would ultimately be filtered out by the `WHERE` clause, but something like this ought to work regardless of the execution plan:

```
case
    when datediff(year, DISPDATE, RTSDATE) < 50
        then datediff(second, DISPDATE, RTSDATE)
    else
        null
end as [IncidentLengthSeconds]
```

It's not pretty, but it should work. Maybe somebody else knows a more concise construction?

Answer (score 0):

My workaround is to add this to the where clause

```
AND 
(
(RTSDATE > REDEPDATE AND DATEDIFF(YEAR, DISPDATE, RTSDATE) < 2) 
OR 
RTSDATE <= REDEPDATE  
)
```

This seems to fix it but I am worried that the plan might again try to perform this after the DATEDIFF SECOND at some point.

The original query works on a 2 month old backup.